# "error LNK1104: cannot open file" during .dll generation

Tags: c++, dll, point-cloud-library, .lib

I am working on a project which uses PCL (boost is one of the programs used by PCL).
the error I'm getting:

> error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   'libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_50.lib'

What I am trying to do is to generate a .dll, this worked before.
I checked the settings of the working and failing projects, and there is no difference in linking, C/C++ settings, yet somehow this one doesn't work.

I don't know if this matters, but it does work as a static library (.lib).

Comment: have you checked the directory paths for .lib?

Comment: are you using libboost functions? why did you tag c#? is that c++/cli project?

Comment: you need to link with the boost library. in your case, the compiler doesn't see where it is. you should go in your project properties > linker > general > include additionnal directory, and add an entry for the boost libraries. if that's already done, then you have not compiled that boost library.

Comment: @ CharlesB I tried to go to Configure->Linker->Input and add the library itself without result

Comment: @Vlad L I tagged C# because this has to go to C#, I guess I shouldn't have done that, I will edit that. I am using libboost yes

Comment: @ Stephane Rolland: This made it worse, I have 9 errors now :P

Comment: @Danahi 9 errors like "unresolved tokens"? than put the dll in the same directory with lib

Comment: @ Vlad L, yes unresolved tokens, sorry I don't get what you mean about the dll in the same directory as the lib?

Comment: @ Vlad L in case u mean that  'libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_50.lib' and the .dll have to be in the same spot, they are.